# What i need to change in my pytorch code?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I try to run following programe for images classification in Pytorch and it returns me
Given groups=1, weight of size [6, 3, 5, 5], expected input[192, 1, 256, 256] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead ?

```
num_classes = 2
class CNN(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self,input_size,n_features,output_size):
    super(CNN, self).__init__()
    self.n_features = n_features
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=n_features,kernel_size=5)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=n_features,out_channels=3*n_features,kernel_size=5)
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3*n_features,out_channels=n_features,kernel_size=5)
    self.conv1_bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(n_features) 
    self.conv2_bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(3*n_features)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(n_features*4*4,2)

  def forward(self,x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = F.relu(self.conv1_bn(x))
    x = F.max_pool2d(x,kernel_size=2)

    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = F.relu(self.conv1_bn(x))
    x = F.max_pool2d(x,kernel_size=2)

    x = x.view(-1,self.n_features*4*4)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = F.log_softmax(x,dim=1)

    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the problem you should change number of `in_channels` in `self.conv1` from 3 to 1, cause from error message it seems you training on images of size `(1, 256, 256)`. Also consider setting stride option of convolutional laeyrs to something more than [default](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) 1, or increasing number of layers.